# I can't see mysql.user table, I need to recover root password

Tags: mysql, privileges

I logged to mysql server using `mysql -ujohn -p`. Then I executed `show databases` and I didn't see the `mysql` database so I can't execute `use mysql`. What I see are `information_schema` and `test` databases. Why can't I see the `mysql` database in order to list `users` table?

Comment: Probably a permissions issue. Try logging in as root.

Comment: Try running the SQL statement [SHOW GRANTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html). Do you have privilege to view any schemas? All users implicitly have privileges to `information_schema` and `test`.

Comment: The thing is I don't have root password and I'm the new in charged on this server. It works for show grants that belongs to john user. I think there is a way to restart or recover root password.